# creating a series of MS Excel graphs with identical properties for a series of tables with different data but same data types

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a series of table in Excel worksheets, all of them holds same data types, one table for one item, and how some values changed over time in each table column.

I want to create a excel graph/chart for each of this table, with same formatting, only the data should be different.

When I copy each from single graph to create many, the table link doesn't change and I have to do that manually, which is difficult because there are number of tables.

Is there any better solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally copied and pasted the same graphs for each table, undo the old links and linked each table separately. I was looking for a easier way than this because even this is difficult with number of tables increasing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The dirtiest solution is to simply use VBA to automate these changes.

Comment: that's exactly what I was afraid of :) anything else I could try before that? Also can you refer me to any VBA sample for that sort of a situation

Comment: How many graphs are we talking about? Is this a one off task or part of a regular cycle?  Changing the source data range for a chart using VBA is not difficult but you need to provide more information about the scale of the problem.

Comment: If your problem is what I think it is, I have found some code to handle it.

Comment: I have set of tables, nearly 100. Each table is for each location. Every tables has similar columns such as temperature, humidity, etc. for 4 quarters f the year. I need to create graphs - ex: humidity change over the 4 quarters for all 100 locations. I could create one graph easily with color, size formatting etc. and I need graphs just like that for other tables. I don't want to draw all 100 separately, how can I extend the first graph so it wil denote each tables respective data with the same formatting. Thank you very much for your help and concern. big help!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extend? Do you want to add series to the graph? It sounds like a job for something more advanced, such as gnuplot.

Comment: I just wanted to have the same type of a graph for each table - but needed an easy way to do that rather than creating a separate one for each, have to copy and paste the graphs, undo the link and link again to the next table :) finally did it this way.